# How to catch a socket-timeout in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I'm writing a server with Java.net. Now i want to change some variables on socket-timeout.

I cant find a 'onTimeout' interface or something similar.

Now I'm searching for a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're using `java.net` so I'm assuming that you're using something like a `java.net.ServerSocket`. If you call [setSoTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) on your instance of `ServerSocket`, you will be able to set a timeout for your socket. Then, when you block during calls to [accept](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()), your `ServerSocket` will keep track of the timeout. As you can see in the documentation, accept throws a `SocketTimeoutException` if a timeout has been defined and the wait time has exceeded the timeout. So, you'll end up with something like this (forgive me for being a bit rusty on `Socket`s):

```
try(ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(...))
{
    ssock.setSoTimeout(10_000); // 10 second timeout
    while(true)
    {
        Socket csock = ssock.accept();
        methodToStartThreadThatHandlesClientSocket(csock);
    }
}
catch(SocketTimeoutException ste)
{
    //handle socket timeout
}
catch(Exception other)
{
    //handle other exceptions
}
```